React: router.push() Não Está Navegando Corretamente no Evento onClick
Eu tenho um código em Next.js e React, estou usando o router.push para acessar outras rotas e funciona mas às vezes o router.push não vai para a o caminho desejado (é possível ver que url do browser fica inalterada) e só faz um recarregamento da página atual. Isso acontece apenas quando eu uso o router.push() em um evento onClick.
Este é um exemplo de como estou implementando o router.push
<button className='btn text-center w-75'
 onClick={() => { router.push('/path') }}>
   <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faTerminal} className='pe-1' /> Base 
</button>


O problema deve acontecer quando você coloca esse button dentro de um <form>, para evitar que ele ocorra, adicione o evento como parâmetro da função e use preventDefault. onClick={(ev) => { ev.preventDefault(); router.push('/path'); }}.
